# start/stop lifecycle of application with sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Let's say there is a simple sbt project describing *myApp* which has configured **sbt-native-packager** with **JavaAppPackaging** as archetype.

I can run `./activator dist` or `./activator stage` commands (`sbt dist` or `sbt stage` if you have sbt) which will create file for running *myApp*. The script will be created in `target/universal/stage/bin/myApp`. This script can run *myApp* in foreground and when I wish to stop it I can do it by pressing `ctr+c` ...

What I need is a something more complicated but still a simple solution for controlling other aspects of running *myApp*.

I would like to start it in a background, restarting it and checking it's status. More over I don't have root access therefore I don't prefer using Java*Server*AppPackaging. Just a simple set of commands like:

- `myApp`  - which will print usage (`usage: myApp [start|stop|restart|status]`)
- `myApp status` - which will print if app is running
- `myApp start` - guess what
- `myApp stop`
- `myApp restart`

will satisfy (not only) my needs.

Any hints?

Comment: What's a use case? Developing, running app in production? Are you sure that you aren't reinventing a wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sbt-native-packager can generate those scripts. You may want to raise feature request with sbt-native-packager team.